# Ратсянуть div на всю высоту табличной ячейки

Tags: javascript, html, css, table

Есть таблица, в каждой ячейке может находится 1 или более блоков с разными цветами фона и внутренним текстом. Внутри ячейки блоки расположены вертикально. Соответственно ячейки с одним блоком выглядят нелепо, он выравнивается по центру, а остальная часть ячейки просто белая. Подскажите как растягивать блоки по всей высоте ячейки.

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>1</th>
    <th>2</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="td-value" style="background-color: #E59B9A;">
      <div style="background-color: #E59B9A;">
        <span class="class-name">ЛФК</span>
        <span class="class-description">09:00- 09:55 (55 мин.) Зал ГП №1</span>
      </div>
      <div style="background-color: #FDE05D;">
        <span class="class-name">ЛФК</span>
        <span class="class-description">09:00- 09:55 (55 мин.) Зал ГП №1</span>
      </div></td>
    <td class="td-value"><td class="td-value"><div style="background-color: #FDE05D;">
      <span class="class-name">FUNCTIONAL TRAINING</span>
      <span class="class-description">13:00- 13:55 (55 мин.) Зал ГП №1</span>
    </div></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Ну можно попробывать задать высоту или добавить td инлайново 
display: table;
table-layout: fixed;

Answer (score 0):

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>1</th>
    <th>2</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="td-value" style="background-color: #E59B9A;">
      <div style="background-color: #E59B9A;">
        <span class="class-name">ЛФК</span>
        <span class="class-description">09:00- 09:55 (55 мин.) Зал ГП №1</span>
      </div>
      <div style="background-color: #FDE05D;">
        <span class="class-name">ЛФК</span>
        <span class="class-description">09:00- 09:55 (55 мин.) Зал ГП №1</span>
      </div></td>
   <td class="td-value" style="height: 1px;"><div style="background-color: #FDE05D; height:100%;">
      <span class="class-name">FUNCTIONAL TRAINING</span>
      <span class="class-description">13:00- 13:55 (55 мин.) Зал ГП №1</span>
    </div></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. К сожалению ячейки где больше одного элемента ломают верстку. Даже если назначить селектор где один элемент. Все равно блок вылазит за границы.

Comment: Понял в чем причина. У меня еще падинг внутри блока.